# Drupal 7 some non-existing URLs are not Redirecting to 404?

Tags: redirect, drupal, drupal-path-aliases

In Drupal 7, some of (non-existing) URLs are not redirecting to 404 or any error page it should. Instead, it still remains showing its Top Parent Folder. For example like:

- www.mywebsite.com/items/aaaaaaaaaaaaa
- www.mywebsite.com/items/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

Every WRONG URLs under `/items/` i put like above, are showing the Page of its parent:
`www.mywebsite.com/items` instead of get redirected to 404
I don't want its parent to be shown **if there is no page really**.

But the strange thing is, it is NOT happening on every patterns. I mean, another different parents like:

- www.mywebsite.com/users/aaaaaaaaaaaaa
- www.mywebsite.com/users/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

For the wrong url typed-in under this `/users/` parent path, it is CORRECTLY redirecting to the 404 page.

What is it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this, really helpfull
http://peterpetrik.com/blog/2009/11/non-existent-urls-views-2

Comment: This note from the Views 404 page helped me : 404s for views can also be accomplished by setting the Global: Null under Arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, it's not a problem at all.

That's because how your/contributed/core modules hooks Drupal menu system.

If a menu item (menu router item to be specific. Think about a path like "admin/config/development/performance") has no "%" sign in it, menu callback function will be executed. 
For an example, if a module registers "items" path example.com/items path would not be a 404, and the appropriate menu callback function of the menu item will be fired. That callback function can make use of further URL parts (example.com/items/123) if given.

'node' is a good example. (technically they are different menu router items though) . 
Opening example.com/node will not fire a 404.

If a module registers 'items/%' , then, example.com/items will fire a 404. In other words, the second URL part is required in order to execute the menu callback function.

If the problem you are facing is related to a custom module, make sure you register the correct version of your router items. If the second URL part is required, register items/%. 
You can execute a 404 by calling [drupal_not_found()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_not_found/7).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) for that path (`/items`)?

Here is an issue for Views: [Prevent duplicate content (because Views returns 200 instead of <del>400</del> 404](http://drupal.org/node/1432230))

You could create a Contextual filter to prevent this.

merlinofchaos [wrote](http://drupal.org/node/1432230#comment-5573704):

> If you don't want this behavior, add the Global: NULL argument to Views and use the setting to validate that the argument is empty.

For Drupal 6, the module [Views 404](http://drupal.org/project/views404) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your drupal installation to redirect to a specefic 404 page that you create..

Go to `www.yoursite.com/admin/config/system/site-information` and enter your 404 page .

Comment: I think this will not work for 4lvin. The error page works for him, _but_ not for _all_ pages.